# Adding missing element on XML using XSLT transformation

Tags: xml, xslt

I am pretty new to writing XSLT transformation logic's so can someone help me out here please.

I am working on XML to XML transformation using XSLT and the idea was to insert missing elements.

Input XML:

```
<EmpJob>    
    <EmpJob>
      <emplStatus>3805</emplStatus>
      <lastName>Jhonny</lastName>
     <firstName>English</firstName>                
     <EmpJobRelationships>      
      <relUserNav>
        <User>
          <defaultName>Crystal</defaultName>
          <userId>00174941</userId>
        </User>
      </relUserNav>      
    </EmpJobRelationships> 
    </EmpJob>
    <EmpJob>
    <emplStatus>3805</emplStatus>      
    <lastName>Tony</lastName>
    <firstName>Romo</firstName>                
    </EmpJob>   
<EmpJob>
```

Desired XML Output with XSLT transformation

```
<EmpJob>    
    <EmpJob>
      <emplStatus>3805</emplStatus>
      <lastName>Johnny</lastName>
     <firstName>English</firstName>                
     <EmpJobRelationships>      
      <relUserNav>
        <User>
          <defaultName>Crystal</defaultName>
          <userId>00174941</userId>
        </User>
      </relUserNav>      
    </EmpJobRelationships> 
    </EmpJob>
    <EmpJob>
    <emplStatus>3805</emplStatus>      
    <lastName>Tony</lastName>
    <firstName>Romo</firstName> 
     <EmpJobRelationships>      
      <relUserNav>
        <User>
          <defaultName></defaultName>
          <userId></userId>
        </User>
      </relUserNav>      
    </EmpJobRelationships>  
    </EmpJob>   
<EmpJob>
```

I tired the below XSLT but the missing elements is once added at the end of the first Parent  but it want it to happen on each of the child . How do I put the logic into a loop so it happens on each of the child

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    
   <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
   <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
   </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/*[not(//EmpJobRelationships)]">
   <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
     <EmpJobRelationships>
      <relationshipType></relationshipType>
      <relUserNav>
        <User>
          <defaultFullName></defaultFullName>
          <userId></userId>
        </User>
      </relUserNav>
      <userId></userId>
      <startDate></startDate>
    </EmpJobRelationships>
   </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Thanks

Comment: What did you try yourself?

Comment: Updated with what I have tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the "missing element" is `EmpJobRelationships` and that it's either present or missing entirely, try:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/EmpJob/EmpJob[not(EmpJobRelationships)]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <EmpJobRelationships>      
            <relUserNav>
                <User>
                    <defaultName/>
                    <userId/>
                </User>
            </relUserNav>      
        </EmpJobRelationships>  
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note the match pattern `/EmpJob/EmpJob` designed to prevent applying the template to the root element of the same name.